# Get "No such file or directory" error in log after camera app finished

Tags: android, kotlin, camera, storage

I am programming apps in Android using Kotlin.

Recently I have run in  to a very peculiar problem.

The system allows me to create a driectory in Extrenal Storage.

Before I have sent a Uri to a file in this directory to the stock camera app and the phot has been stored in it.

Recently the result has been  "No such file or driectory" when the camera app tries to store the image.

Any ideas what is wrong?

I have the following provider in my AndroidManifest:

```
    <provider
   android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
   android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
   ndroid:exported="false"
   android:grantUriPermissions="true">
   <meta-data
       android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
       android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

And the provider_paths looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
           <paths>
              <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
           </paths>
```

The external-path **name** ends up as part of the content uri,

```
content://se.miljotekniska.android.mt.lista.kone.debug.provider
    /external_files/MT/63301/000.jpg
```

Trying to access this uri gives the above mentioned error

I am not able to create an directory in the public storage.

```
val path = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "/test")
path.mkdirs()
```

path.mkdirs() returns false

Storing a camera image in a specific location.

I get "No such file or Directory"

Comment: What are you expectiong of stackoverflow?

Comment: Wrote more specific about the problem.

Comment: You could be more specific. Post some code. There is no code at all. We dont know what you do.

Comment: addes the first code part that does not work

Comment: `path.mkdirs() returns false` Yes. It will if the directory already exists. Check before use. Further the title of your post does not match this problem

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve my problem.

The error was that i put

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, inmageUri)
```

to a choose Intent instead of an `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` Intent.

When the correct Intent got the output position the error went away.